# JXL Changing Columns for JSOUP-based Application

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, jxl

Currently, this program will run down a column of URLs and output the selected data to the neighboring cell. I can set which column it starts on, but that is all I can do. Right now, I only have it working on one column. How can I instruct it to go to say, column 4 (Column E) and work top down once it is through with column 0 (A)? And then perhaps another, say column J after that?

I believe my problem lies within the "while (!(cell = sheet.getCell..." line, but I am unsure of what to change there without breaking the program.

My code is as follows:

```
public class App {

private static final int URL_COLUMN = 0; // Column A
private static final int PRICE_COLUMN = 1; //Column B

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    Workbook originalWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/original.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/updated.xls"), originalWorkbook);
    originalWorkbook.close();
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    int currentRow = 1;
    Cell cell;

    while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMN, currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {

        String url = cell.getContents();
        System.out.println("Checking URL: " + url);
        if (url.contains("scrapingsite1.com")) {
            String Price = ScrapingSite1(url);
            System.out.println("Scraping Site1's Price: " + Price);
            Label cellWithPrice = new Label(PRICE_COLUMN, currentRow, Price);
            sheet.addCell(cellWithPrice);
        }
        currentRow++;
    }
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}

private static String ScrapingSite1 (String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = null;
    for (int i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(6000).validateTLSCertificates(false).get();
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Jsoup issue occurred " + i + " time(s).");
        }
    }
    if (doc == null){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return doc.select("p.price").text();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the code I made an assumption that the price comes always to the next column (+1).

Also to process few columns instead of using single value `int URL_COLUMN = 0` I replaced it with array of columns to process: `int[] URL_COLUMNS = { 0, 4, 9 }; // Columns A, E, J`.

You can then loop over every column `{0, 4, 9}` and save the data to the next column `{1, 5, 10}`.

```
    private static final int[] URL_COLUMNS = { 0, 4, 9 }; // Columns A, E, J

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        Workbook originalWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/original.xls"));
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/updated.xls"), originalWorkbook);
        originalWorkbook.close();
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        Cell cell;

        // loop over every column
        for (int i = 0; i < URL_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
            int currentRow = 1;
            while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMNS[i], currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {

                String url = cell.getContents();
                System.out.println("Checking URL: " + url);
                if (url.contains("scrapingsite1.com")) {
                    String Price = ScrapingSite1(url);
                    System.out.println("Scraping Site1's Price: " + Price);
                    // save price into the next column
                    Label cellWithPrice = new Label(URL_COLUMNS[i] + 1, currentRow, Price);
                    sheet.addCell(cellWithPrice);
                }
                currentRow++;
            }
        }

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

Comment: Krystian, first, thank you very much! It's perfect!

Second, do you think it would be possible to code in current processes to run this quicker? Or would this be limited by JXL's ability to read and write concurrently? I was thinking each column could run two of its own processes, each will every n+2 rows, and one will start at n=0 and the other at n=1. This would have one process run every other row and the other process run the opposite ones, and there would be 6 concurrent threads total, 2 per column. What do you think? Would I be limited by JXL? Thanks again!

Comment: JXL's `sheet.addCell();` is internally using ArrayList which is not thread safe, but it's possible to synchronize `addCell` so it may be possible to speed it up using threads. The most time consuming operation will be downloading and parsing so it won't be a problem, but you never mentioned concurrency in your original question and it's not that trivial to process it in scope of this question.

Comment: I actually don't know anything about concurrency, so I wasn't sure how difficult it could be to implement. Any resources that could point me in the right direction? Or should I ask as a separate question (not sure about rules here)? Thanks again!

Comment: Another question would be more suitable but everything you need (actually much more) can be found in the official tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ It may bee too complicated at first as it contains a lot of theory but any googled "java concurrency tutorial" should be fine. Try something new :)